# Where to place prisma seed.ts in Next.js 13 with appDir to apply seed data into supabase?

Tags: next.js, prisma, supabase, next.js13, supabase-database

I am trying to apply seed data into supabase database from the Next.js 13 app that using appDir. In some tutorials and articles, you can place seed file in `pages/api` and once it runs next api server, seed data would be applied. I want to try that, but the project built with Next.13 with appDir, it doesn't have `pages` directory.
[Project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMucD.png)

I tried to place seed file in `app/api` instead of `pages/api`, and run next api server, but it didn't work.

Also, I tried another way to apply seed which is to place seed.ts in prisma folder that has schema.prisma, and run `npx prisma db seed` with the script and prisma settings like below:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-learn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "seed": "node prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "4.12.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.21",
    "prisma": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "node --loader ts-node/esm prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I would be glad to learn how to apply seed in next.js 13 with appDir.

Answer (score 0):

All you need it's just create folder pages/api and put your seed.ts inside and then go to localhost:3000/api/seed. Pages folder should not be inside app directory, this folder must be in the root directory of the project